# Are the AARP benefits and discounts worth the yearly membership cost?

Tags: united-states, life-insurance, memberships

When considering organizations like AARP, what are the factors that makes these types of organizations valuable to members?

Our main interests is to obtain term life insurance.

I am sure there are other benefits other than insurance, any suggestions will be welcomed.

---

EDIT#1

Based on the amount of responses I am guessing that there is a very limited number of Personal Finance members that are close or over 50 years of age.  I am listing below some of the "Benefits" of being a member to see if I can drive a few more responses.

- Travel Benefits
- Discounts on stres
- Health Products
- Insurance Products
- Financial Services
- Volunteer Opportunities
- Advocacy

---

Comment: For my wife and I we are not members of any such organization. We both work, and what is not covered by work we shop around for. For us, it's just a layer of management (with associated costs) that we can do without.

Comment: As someone older who is older than 50, let me say that you should also look at other sources (in addition to those enumerated by mhoran_psprep) for term life insurance such as your professional society (e.g. IEEE, ACM, APS) or other organization: for example, TIAA offers low-cost term life insurance to school teachers and college professors and their spouses. The other thing to consider is _how much_ life insurance is needed if you have an empty nest and have Social Security benefits, 401K/403b plans, IRAs etc also available at levels much larger than when you were younger.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: this answer was provided when the question was only about Life Insurance, therefore it does not address any other "benefits"**

Term Life Insurance is very easy to evaluate, once you have determined how much you need and for how long. For significant amounts of coverage they may require a physical to be performed. The price quotes will be for  two levels of health, so you can compare costs from many companies quite easily.

You have several sources in no particular order: employer, independent company, 3rd party like AARP, AAA, or via you bank or credit union. Note that the 3rd party will be getting a cut of the premium. Also some choices offered from the employer or 3rd party may be limited in size or duration. The independent companies will be able to have terms that extend for 10 years or more.

So view the insurance offered by AARP as just another option that has to be compared to all your other options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate the direction on how to compare life insurance options. Do you think the $16/year cost of AARP will bring $16 or more of savings? Why?

Comment: No way to tell, until you get quotes. It is possible that AARP is the most expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you.

If you're not an aggressive shopper and travel , you'll recoup your membership fee in hotel savings with one or two stays. Hilton brands, for example, give you a 10% discount. AARP discounts can sometimes be combined with other offers as well.

From an insurance point of view, you should always shop around, but sometimes group plans like AARP's have underwriting standards that work to your advantage.